# Parallel `for` loop with an array as output

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, parallel-processing

How can I run a `for` loop in parallel (so I can use all the processors on my windows machine) with the result being a 3 dimension array? The code I have now takes about an hour to run and is something like:

```
guad = array(NA,c(1680,170,15))
for (r in 1:15)
{
  name = paste("P:/......",r,".csv",sep="")
  pp = read.table(name,sep=",",header=T)
    #lots of stuff to calculate x (which is a matrix)
  guad[,,r]= x  #
}
```

I have been looking at related questions and thought I could use `foreach` but I couldn't find a way to combine the matrices into an array.

I am new to parallel programming so any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Look at the `.combine` parameter of `foreach`. You don't need to pre-allocate `guad` with `foreach` and each iteration should only return a matrix. All matrices can then be combined to an array by `foreach`. Study the help pages and package vignette.

Comment: I did look at `.combine` but it only allows c,cbind,rbind or a function so how can I combine the matrices to an array?

Comment: By passing [a function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15213463/1412059) to `.combine` that binds matrices into an array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do that with `foreach` using the `abind` function.  Here's an example using the `doParallel` package as the parallel backend which is fairly portable:

```
library(doParallel)
library(abind)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)
acomb <- function(...) abind(..., along=3)
guad <- foreach(r=1:4, .combine='acomb', .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
  x <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4)  # compute x somehow
  x  # return x as the task result
}
```

This uses a combine function called `acomb` that uses the `abind` function from the `abind` package to combine the matrices generated by the cluster workers into a 3 dimensional array.

In this case, you can also combine the results using `cbind` and then modify the `dim` attribute afterwards to convert the resulting matrix into a 3 dimensional array:

```
guad <- foreach(r=1:4, .combine='cbind') %dopar% {
  x <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4)  # compute x somehow
  x  # return x as the task result
}
dim(guad) <- c(4,4,4)
```

The use of `abind` is useful since it can combine matrices and arrays in a variety of ways.  Also, be aware that resetting the `dim` attribute may cause the matrix to be duplicated which could be a problem for large arrays.

Note that it's a good idea to shutdown the cluster at the end of the script using `stopCluster(cl)`.

Comment: thanks for the help! I used your first example and it seems to be working :)