# Dealing with multidimensional output in parallel programming

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing

I am currently working on a program to evaluate the out-of-sample performance of several forecasting models on simulated data. For those who are familiar with finance, it works exactly like backtesting a trading strategy, except that I would evaluate forecasts and not transactions.

Some of the objects I currently manipulate using for loops for this type of task are 7 dimensional arrays (dimensions stand for Monte Carlo replications, data generating processes, forecast horizons, 3 dimensions for model parameter selection, and one dimension for all the periods covered in the out-of-sample analysis). Obviously, it is painfully slow, so parallel computing has became a must for me.

My problem is: how do I keep track of more than 2 dimensions in R? Let's just show you using 'for loops' and only 3 dimensions what I mean:

```
x <- array(dim=c(2,2,2))
     for (i in 1:2){
       for (j in 1:2){
         for (k in 1:2){
           x[i,j,k] <- i+j+k
         }
       }
     }
```

If I use something like 'foreach', I am very annoyed by the fact that, to my knowledge, available combining functionalities will return lists, matrices or vectors -- but not arbitrarily large multidimensional arrays. For instance:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

# Get the number of cores to use
no_cores <- max(1, detectCores()-1)

# Make cluster object using no_cores
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

# Initialize cluster for parallel computing
registerDoParallel(cl)

x <- foreach(i=1:2, .combine=rbind)%:%
       foreach(j=1:2, .combine=cbind)%:%
         foreach(k=1:2, .combine=c)%dopar%{
           i+j+k
     }
```

Here, I basically combine results into vectors, then matrices and, finally, I pile up matrices by rows. Another option would be to use lists, or pile matrices through columns, but you can imagine the mess when you have 7 dimensions and millions of iterations to track.

I suppose I could also write my own 'combine' function and get the kind of output I want, but I suspect that I am not the first person to encounter this problem. Either there is a way to do exactly what I want, or someone here can point out a way to think differently about storing my results. It wouldn't be surprising that I am taking an absurdly inefficient path toward solving this problem -- I am an economist, not a data scientist, after all!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I would do and I already use in one of my packages, bigstatsr.**

Take only **one** dimension and cut it in `no_cores` blocks. It should have sufficient iterations (e.g. 20 for 4 cores). For each iteration, construct part of the array you want and store it in a temporary file. The, use the content of these files to fill the whole array. By doing so, you fill only preallocated objects, which should be faster and easier.

Example:

```
x.all <- array(dim=c(20,2,2))
no_cores <- 3    
tmpfile <- tempfile()    
range.parts <- bigstatsr:::CutBySize(nrow(x.all), nb = no_cores)

library(foreach)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(no_cores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(ic = 1:no_cores) %dopar% {

  ind <- bigstatsr:::seq2(range.parts[ic, ])
  x <- array(dim = c(length(ind), 2, 2))

  for (i in seq_along(ind)){
    for (j in 1:2){
      for (k in 1:2){
        x[i,j,k] <- ind[i]+j+k
      }
    }
  }

  saveRDS(x, file = paste0(tmpfile, "_", ic, ".rds"))
}
parallel::stopCluster(cl)

for (ic in 1:no_cores) {
  ind <- bigstatsr:::seq2(range.parts[ic, ])
  x.all[ind, , ] <- readRDS(paste0(tmpfile, "_", ic, ".rds"))
}

print(x.all)
```

Instead of writing files, you could also directly return the `no_cores` parts of the array in `foreach` and combine them with the right `abind`.

Comment: It is actually a very good solution. It did take me some time working with R to 'get' what you were trying to do here, but I'll keep this suggestion on the back burner until I have some new fancy work to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is one available solution that I finally stumbled upon tonight. I can create an appropriate combination function along the dimension of my choice using the 'abind' function of the 'abind' package:

```
library(abind)

# Get the number of cores to use
no_cores <- max(1, detectCores()-1)

# Make cluster object using no_cores
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

# Initialize cluster for parallel computing
registerDoParallel(cl)

mbind <- function(...) abind(..., along=3)

x <- foreach(i=1:2, .combine=mbind)%:%
   foreach(j=1:2, .combine=cbind)%:%
     foreach(k=1:2, .combine=c)%dopar%{
       i+j+k
 }
```

I would still like to see if someone has other means of doing what I want to do, however. There might be many ways to do it and I am new to R, yet this solution is a distinct possibility.

Comment: This is the package and approach that I use, but you should use the `.multicombine=TRUE` option along with `mbind`, otherwise `mbind` will never be called with more than two arguments, which can significantly hurt your performance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17572065/2109128 for my answer to a similar question.