# How to fill a very large array in parallel R

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I need to fill a lot of very large arrays by opening up thousands of csv files, extracting columns of data, and inserting them into 3D and 4D matrices.  I've tried writing this in parallel, but what always happens is that my computer crashes when my memory fills up.  I've looked at this question, [Parallel `for` loop with an array as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570806/parallel-for-loop-with-an-array-as-output), but I have not gotten those suggestions to work for me.  Here's my code (generalized where needed):

```
tmin_array_1981_2010 <- array(NA,c(585,1386,366))
foreach (f = 1:500000, .packages=c('dplyr','lubridate')) %dopar% {
    data <- read.csv(file_name[f])
    tmin_array_1981_2010[y[f],x[f],] = data$column}
```

There's a lot more that I'm doing in the foreach loop, but this is enough to understand what I want to do.  I've read that I can use an lapply statement to parallelize this code, but I'm not going to pretend I understand what, or how, they're doing it.  I've also tried using the abind function as shown in this post, [Parallel `for` loop with an array as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570806/parallel-for-loop-with-an-array-as-output), but this performs worse than the simple code I have above.

```
acomb <- function(...) abind(..., along=3)
foreach (f=1:18, .combine='acomb', .multicombine=TRUE, .packages=c('dplyr','lubridate','vroom','tidyverse')) %dopar% {
    data <- read.csv(file_name[f])
    tmin_array_1981_2010[y[f],x[f],] = data$column}
```

Any help would great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the part taking time is reading the CSVs.

So you can always return `list(y[f], x[f], data$column)` (or even just `data$column`) and fill the array later. Do not use `.combine` then.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I was hoping that something would allow me to read the csv file and fill the array in the same loop, but this is fine.  Thank you.