# How to stack multiple matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of matrices, similar to the one obtained by the code below:

```
a <- matrix(1, ncol=2, nrow=3)
b <- matrix(2, ncol=2, nrow=3)
c <- matrix(3, ncol=2, nrow=3)
d <- list(a, b, c)
```

I want to stack them so that they are in one matrix, similar to this one:

```
e <- rbind(d[[1]], d[[2]], d[[3]])
```

The trick is that I don't know in advance how many matrices will need to be joined.  Is there a good way to write code that will stack all matrices in the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A classic `do.call` :

```
     do.call(rbind,d)
```

Another option using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(d,as.data.frame))
```

Comment: The latter way is very slow. If you really want a data.table, do the binding with matrices first and then convert.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(plyr)
ldply(d)
  1 2
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 1
4 2 2
5 2 2
6 2 2
7 3 3
8 3 3
9 3 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions.  First, using the base package

```
e <- do.call(rbind, d)
```

will join the list of matrices.

Second, using the package `abind`:

```
library(abind)
e <- abind(d, along=1)
```

If you have data frames instead of matrices, `data.table::rbindlist(d)` is a faster option than `do.call(rbind, d)`.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite...

```
Reduce(rbind, d)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with all solutions so far is that when matrices (not `data.frame`s - for this `dplyr` and `data.table` work fine) do not have the same order of rows and columns, bind will stack values over each other that do not relate.

If you want to check and take into account the names in each dimension, have a look at [`narray`](https://github.com/mschubert/narray):

[image]

(disclaimer: I wrote the package)