# Adding a matrix to a list in R

Tags: arrays, r, image

I have a list corresponding to the matrix of a .png image without the RGB transparency information. The dimension of the matrix is `128 128 3`. So I have a `128 x 128` matrix coding the red hues in each pixel; a `128 x 128` matrix coding the greens; and a `128 x 128` matrix for the blues. There is no transparency in the image, but to write this .png, I think I need to include a `128x128` matrix of `1`'s and tag it to my list so as to get a `128 x 128 x 4` matrix.

How can I append this matrix of ones to my list?

I have a list named `compressed` with these dimensions (`128 128 3`), and I've tried multiple single and double-bracketed ways to include something like `matrix(rep(1, 128^2), nrow= 128)` without success.

The idea is to eventually save it as:

```
require(png)
writePNG(compressed, "compressed.picture")
```

without doing away with color.

Comment: Do you have a `list` or `array`  If it is a `list` just `do c(yourlist, yourmatrix)` or use `append` or assign as new `list` element with `[[`

Comment: [Library vs. require - Yihui](http://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/) :)

Comment: Actually, the alpha channel is optional, so you don't need to append the fourth matrix filled with `1`'s to your color channels. Providing the `128 x 128 x 3` array to `writePNG` should be just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example depending on whether you have an array or a list of matrices currently. Looking at `?writePNG` it seems you need a `n x n x 4` array as the final product, so I included a conversion from list to array.

Plenty of other solutions are offered e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213463/combining-matrices-into-an-array-in-r).

```
n <- 4

# generate matrices
r <- matrix(runif(n^2), n, n)
g <- matrix(runif(n^2), n, n)
b <- matrix(runif(n^2), n, n)
a <- matrix(1, n, n)

# list or array format for the data you have
li <- list(r, g, b)
ar <- array(c(r, g, b), dim = c(n, n, 3))

# appending the fourth matrix
li[[4]] <- a
ar1 <- array(c(ar, a), dim = c(n, n, 4))

# alternatively for array
library(abind)
ar2 <- abind(ar, a, along = 3)

# if you have a list and need an array
sapply(li, identity, simplify = "array")
```