# How do I repeat an argument n times in a function?

Tags: r

I get this at times when making datasets. I can usually use `rep`, but sometimes it doesn't apply and I have to find a workaround or write an inordinately long function call.

For example, I need to make a 3-d array out of identical 2-d matrices, using the `abind` function. If I want 5 copies, it isn't elegant but could be worse:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1), nrow=3, ncol=3)
abind(mat, mat, mat, mat, mat, along=3)
```

If I want 200 copies, is there a cleaner solution than repeating the argument 200 times? Using `rep` concatenates the matrices, and I've tried other functions without any luck. I'd like to avoid loops and `eval(parse(text=...))` if I can.

Comment: Also relevant for the instance of the matrices not all being the same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213463/combining-matrices-into-an-array-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?replicate` is what you want:

```
replicate(5, mat)
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    1
#
#  <snip!>
#  
#, , 5
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    1
```

...which is a shortcut for `replicate(5, mat, simplify="array")`. Change the `simplify=` argument to `FALSE` or `TRUE` to see other possible output options.

If the `abind` function is needed for a different output (e.g. using `along=2` for instance), then you could hack together:

```
do.call(abind, c(rep(list(mat), 5), along=3) )
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Suppose the function to be called is `expand.grid`; how would I call it with, say, 3 copies of `c(TRUE, FALSE)`? The `replicate` function isn't working as I'm hoping.

Comment: @AdrianKeister - it depends what you want as output exactly - do you just want `expand.grid(rep(list(c(TRUE,FALSE)),3))` ? If it's more complicated you might want to post a new question.

Comment: Oh, that is what I wanted! I didn't have the `list` call in there, so I was doing `expand.grid(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 3))`, and that was silly. Many thanks!