# R abind function with list of objects

Tags: r

I am looking to use the abind function in package abind to join a large number of 2d objects (M1, M2 .....) into a 3d array

If I do:

```
abind(M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4, along=3)
```

I get the desired result

but if I generate a list matrix:

```
list_matrix <- list(ls(pattern="M_"))
```

and then:

```
abind(list_matrix, along=3)
```

I get an error.

Am I missing something obvious? I want to use the list_matrix to avoid manually writing out M1 etc.

Comment: `abind(list_matrix, along=3)` works just fine for me, as per this answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15213601/496803

Answer (score 1):

If we need a `list` of matrices then just use `mget`

```
list_matrix <- mget(ls(pattern="M_\\d+"))
```

or a 3D array, then convert the above `list` to array with `do.call`

```
ar1 <- do.call(abind, c(list_matrix, along = 3))
```

OP's code

```
ar2 <- abind(M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4, along=3)
all.equal(ar1, ar2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned

```
abind(list_matrix, along=3)
```

#### data

```
M_1 <- matrix(1:25, 5 , 5)
M_2 <- matrix(26:50, 5, 5)
M_3 <- matrix(51:75, 5, 5)
M_4 <- matrix(76:100, 5, 5)
```

Comment: Just `abind(list_matrix, along=3)` works for me as per `?abind` - "*Alternatively, there can be one (and only one) list argument
          supplied, whose components are the objects to be bound
          together.*"