# R, controlling population of array from matrices and vector

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

If I start with two equally sized 2,5-matrices:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2)
m2 <-  matrix(11:20, nrow = 2)
```

I am trying to improve my array skills (inspired by [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213463/combining-matrices-into-an-array-in-r)), but cannot think of an "generic" way using base R to bind them to an 2,2,5-array `a` so that:

```
> a[1,,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

I can use the package abind and obtain the required:

```
> a <- abind::abind(m1, m2, along = 0 )
> a[1,,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

> all(a[1,,]==m1)
[1] TRUE
```

1) How to do this using base R

2) Can the same be done without creating `m1` and `m2` ? (This works not: `array(1:20, dim = c(2, 2, 5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `rbind` first

```
b <- array(rbind(1:10, 11:20), dim = c(2, 2, 5))
b[1,,]
```

Result

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

---

The way presented above fills your array with this vector

```
#[1] 1 11  2 12  3 13  4 14  5 15  6 16  7 17  8 18  9 19 10 20
```

which is what we get when we call

```
c(rbind(1:10, 11:20))
```

---

Another option would be

```
array(matrix(1:20, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE), dim = c(2, 2, 5))
```

here the part `matrix(1:20, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)` has the same effect as `rbind(1:10, 11:20)` shown above.

Comment: But this will not give the structure required (with a[1,,] equals m1 and a[2,,] equals m2.

Comment: yes that was better - will now try to digest why `rbind` does it. Can it be extended to 4 dim ?